# I got problem with replacing jmenubar on jpanel

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a desktop application using java swing with netbeans gui manager. I want replace vertical menu with submenus on Jpanel but when I am putting Jmenubar on Jpanel it does not work. I need some help with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's much better if you share your non-working code as a minimal reproducible example so that the proposed solution actually applies to your problem and can help future visitors with the same problem. Otherwise, there's a high likelihood that people will be tossing out random solutions that might not help you (or anyone else) much. See How to Ask and take the tour for more information on how to ask an on-topic question

Comment: @Standin.Wolf means [ask] (as in `[ask]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JMenubBar` is designed to be added to the `JFrame` using the `setJMenuBar(...)` method.

If you want to use popup menus for other Swing components then you should be using a `JPopupMenu`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for more information and working examples to get you started.